# C# to VB .NET yield return conversion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What's the translation of this snippet in VB .NET?

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
Func<TSource, Boolean> predicate)
{
  foreach (TSource element in source)
  {
    if (predicate(element))
    yield return element;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here isn't converting an extension method - it's converting an iterator block (the method uses `yield return`. VB doesn't have any equivalent language construct - you'd have to create your own implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which did the filtering, then return an instance of the class from the extension method.

That's exactly what the C# compiler does, but it's hidden behind the scenes.

One point to note, which might not be obvious otherwise: `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`, and a `foreach` loop disposes of the iterator at the end. This can be very important - so if you *do* create your own implementation of this (and I'd recommend that you don't, frankly) you'll need to call `Dispose` on the iterator returned from `source.GetEnumerator()` in your own `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 5):

This question is old, but for people coming here from Google there is good news - new releases of VB.NET have support for the c# yield return operator (I believe this isn VS.NET 2010/2012 w/ .net 4.0)...  Here is the converted sample:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Iterator Function Where(Of TSource)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), predicate As Func(Of TSource, [Boolean])) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
    '' non-lambda version of the method body
    'For Each element As TSource In source
    '    If predicate(element) Then
    '        Yield element
    '    End If 
    'Next
    For Each element As TSource In From item In source Where predicate(item)
        Yield element
    Next
End Function
```

There is no need to change static to shared as VB.NET extension methods must be defined in Modules which are automatically 'shared' or static.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, VB.net has no equivalent to the `yield` keyword. In order to implement the `yield` functionality, you'll have to look at doing some fancy moves with `IEnumerable<T>`... you can check out [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/02/01/Use-Iterators-in-VB-Now.aspx?Page=1) for a good walkthrough.

If you're just looking for the syntax for extension methods, here's what it would look like:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function Where(Of TSource) ( _
                ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), _
                ByVal predicate As Func(Of TSource, [Boolean])) _
       As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that VB does not support iterator blocks. Can you not just use the existing `Enumerable.Where` method from VB?

The other lazy way of doing it in VB would be to consume and filter the entire sequence *first* - and just return the resulting array/list, but that wouldn't have the deferred execution that C# iterator blocks offer. Which is a pain; I often use iterator blocks with long (i.e. essentially infinite) sequences.