# How to convert C# keyword yield to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Translation of yield into VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811589/translation-of-yield-into-vb-net)
>   [Yield in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net)

I try to convert the C# yield to VB.NET but i found there is no yield in VB.NET
anyone pls ?

```
Public Function GetHalfAnHourChunks(ByVal startFrom As DateTime, ByVal until As DateTime) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
        '        While startFrom < until
        '       yield Return startFrom
        '            startFrom = startFrom.AddMinutes(30)
        '        End While
        '    End Function
```

Comment: There is not equivalent to `yield` in VB.Net. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net) thread

Comment: Thx very much guyz. Sorry for duplicating the post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of 'yield' in VB.Net

*Edit* I stand somewhat corrected - see [Yield in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net)

Comment: It isn't in the language yet.  That link describes a CTP release, which will come out with a new Visual Studio some time in 2012

Comment: Thx guyz. Finally i solved using another method