# Why is Array.Sort() so slow compared to LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I made quick testing application to compare LINQ sorting to Array.Sort on my custom objects.
Array.Sort seems extremely slow!

I made my custom class like this:

```
class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person obj)
    {
        return this.Age.CompareTo(obj.Age);
    }

    public Person()
    { }

}
```

Then i made my testing persons in main() :

```
string name = "Mr. Tomek";

Random r = new Random();
int size = 10000000;

DateTime start, end;
Person[] people1 = new Person[size];
Person[] people2 = new Person[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     people1[i] = new Person();
     people1[i].Age = r.Next(0, 10000);
     people1[i].Name = name;

     people2[i] = new Person();
     people2[i].Age = people1[i].Age;
     people2[i].Name = people1[i].Name;
}
```

After that i have measured time taken to Sort by Array.Sort and by LINQ:

```
start = DateTime.Now;
var sort = from s in people2
           orderby s.Age
           select s;
end = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("LINQ: ");
Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);

start = DateTime.Now;
Array.Sort(people1,((Person p1, Person p2)=>{return p1.CompareTo(p2);}));
end = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine("IComparable: ");
Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Linq time: about 1 or 2 miliseconds

Array.Sort: over 16 **SECONDS!**

All arrays are sorted (LINQ produces new collection and leaves oryginal array unsorted) but Array.Sort is extremely slow! How could it be explained? (in DEBUG and RELEASE mode Array.Sort fails extremely)

I pasted code with lambda expression when sorting with Array.Sort but it's the same with and without it. (Class Person implements IComparable interface)

Comment: You might be interested in my related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance

Comment: @TomaszSikora: You can simply sort by calling `Array.Sort(people1)`, since the `IComparable<T>` implementation is used automatically.

Comment: I did notice something... Linq is faster when sorting bigger arrays. Array.Sort is faster when Array is less than 100 000 elements. Why is that happening?

Comment: The key thing to understand here is that the result of a query expression is **a query**.  It is not **the results of the query**. Also: use Stopwatch for timing, not DateTime.Now. You will get  results that are both more accurate and more precise.

Comment: @Marc that question is not related to this at all. Here OP isn't executing the call.

Comment: Please use a stopwatch to get a more accurate reading for the time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your Linq query doesn't even get executed because you don't get the results. That's called [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). The query is only executed when you actually enumerate over the results.

Use something like `var results = sort.ToArray()` to execute the query, then you will get more accurate results.

Comment: Code that doesn't execute will always out perform executing code!

Comment: I hope the OP doesn't feel silly. It's a **very** common issue/mistake I've seen (and probably have done myself): Not knowing or understanding when you're actually enumerating an IEnumerable and when you're just altering it. I think more common than this is the issue where you cost yourself efficiency by enumerating your IEnumerable multiple times.

Comment: @blesh Yes, it surely isn't the first thing people get to know about Linq :)

Answer (score 14):

LINQ is lazy. Your `people2` hasn't actually been sorted, LINQ just created a temporary "promise object" that it *would be* sorted. To make it actually happen, you have to force the evaluation by `Console.WriteLine` the sorted result, convert it into list/array or do anything else like this.

See more: [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

Linq statements return `IEnumerable<T>` or flavours of, this (or anything using the `yield` keyword) only executes when you *iterate* it. Most actions available from the Linq libraries (not all) [are lazy / deferred](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx).

You are not iterating it, so you are not actually performing the sort.

You need to force a full iteration. Sticking the results in a List will fully iterate the returned enumerable:

```
var sort = (from s in people2
            orderby s.Age
            select s).ToList();
```

Only then will you be comparing apples to apples.

In fact, in the case of a sort (`orderby`), simply selecting the *first* item will cause a full iteration as a sort needs to be done fully before you can return the first result:

```
var sort = from s in people2
           orderby s.Age
           select s;

var s = sort.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this part and do your test once again.

```
    start = DateTime.Now;
    var sort = (from s in people2
               orderby s.Age
               select s).ToList();
    end = DateTime.Now;
```

This will evaluate LINQ expression.