# Why is OrderBy which returns IOrderedEnumerable<T> much faster than Sort?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, collections

This is a follow up of this excellent question [C# Sort and OrderBy comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832684/c-sharp-sort-and-orderby-comparison). I will use the same example:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person("P005", "Janson"));
persons.Add(new Person("P002", "Aravind"));
persons.Add(new Person("P007", "Kazhal"));
```

The methods in contention are:

```
persons.Sort((p1, p2) => string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name, true));
//and
persons.OrderBy(n => n.Name);
```

Let me start by saying that I understand there isn't any significant performance difference to worry about. But I would love to know why does `OrderBy` perform so much better than `Sort`. I'm using the answer posted by @phoog in the original question.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Person> people;

    BenchMark(persons => persons.Sort((p1, p2) => string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name, true)));

    BenchMark(persons => people = persons.OrderBy(n => n.Name));
}

private static Random randomSeed = new Random();
public static string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(size);
    int start = (lowerCase) ? 97 : 65;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sb.Append((char)(26 * randomSeed.NextDouble() + start));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

private static void BenchMark(Action<List<Person>> action)
{
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        persons.Add(new Person("P" + i.ToString(), RandomString(5, true)));
    }
    List<Person> unsortedPersons = new List<Person>(persons);

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        watch.Start();

        action(persons);

        watch.Stop();
        persons.Clear();
        persons.AddRange(unsortedPersons);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

**Result:**

```
Sort() => 3500 ~ 5000 ms
OrderBy() => 0.2 ~ 1.5 ms
```

Though differences were profound even with smaller lists I tested initially, it became more and more glaring once the size of the collection went up. May be I'm missing something key to understanding .NET collections, but my thinking is since `Sort` acts on an existing `List<T>`, it should have lesser overhead (if every any) in processing when compared to `OrderBy` which acts on the same `List<T>` (in our case `persons`) but have to return another collection [`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852.aspx). But still `OrderBy` performs far far better. `List<T>` might have certain overhead compared to `IEnumerable<T>` type, but `Sort` anyway acts on the existing list! Furthermore, I'm little amused to see a `Linq` method working faster than existing .NET method.

All the answers in the original question compare `Sort` against `OrderBy.ToList` which I believe will have some overhead and therefore performs more or less equally.

What could be the implementation differences?

---

**Edit:** Ok I learned something new. Here is how I confirmed about deferred execution.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BenchMark(persons =>
    {
        persons.Sort((p1, p2) => string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name, true));
        foreach (var item in persons)
        {
            break;
        }
    });

    BenchMark(persons =>
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> people = persons.OrderBy(n => n.Name);
        foreach (var item in people)
        {
            break;
        }
    });
}
```

`Sort` ran in 4000 - 5000ms while `OrderBy` ran just above 5000ms. So indeed my conclusion was wrong. Both of them performed on equal terms once I started to enumerate the collections. I prefer the syntax of `OrderBy` anyday :)

**Edit 2:** I just found that this is exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299464/why-is-array-sort-so-slow-compared-to-linq?lq=1). But here is a [more interesting question about deferred execution in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance) though not about ordering altogether.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Array.Sort() so slow compared to LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299464/why-is-array-sort-so-slow-compared-to-linq)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In this case, `OrderBy` is far faster because you're not actually executing it.

Until you enumerate the results, the query is *deferred*, so it's never actually doing the ordering.  Until you actually enumerate through the results, the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` doesn't process the input and do any form of ordering.

Try changing your benchmark to:

```
 BenchMark(persons => people = persons.OrderBy(n => n.Name).Count());
```

The `Count()` call will force the ordering to actually occur (since it needs to enumerate the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` to generate a count), which should even out your timings significantly.

Most LINQ extension methods work this way - until you enumerate them (via `Count()`, calling `ToList()`, or just using them in a normal `foreach` loop, etc), they will have negligible impact, as they don't actually do anything directly other than build the enumerable.  The reason the other benchmarks compare to `OrderBy(...).ToList()` is that the addition of `ToList()` forces the `OrderBy` to fully execute and actually order the results.

Comment: Reed, what do you mean by not actually doing the ordering? I can enumerate the `IOrderedEnumerable` returned and print the objects in it to verify the objects are ordered

Comment: As long as Microsoft haven't been sneaky and realised they don't need to sort the collection in order to return its count... :p

Comment: @nawfal Yes, but until you actually enumerate that collection, the results haven't actually been ordered yet. They are ordered immediately after you request enumeration (and before the results are actually returned).

Comment: @nawfal THe ordering occurs *when you enumerate the results*, but not before.  Until you actually fetch the results, all it does is build an enumerable that says "make sure I return the results ordered when asked"

Comment: @Rawling At least for now, this optimization isn't in place.  `OrderBy` always returned an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, and there is no version of that class which implements `ICollection<T>`, so the normal `Count()` optimization for `ICollection<T>`  won't happen.

Comment: I figured that, but allow me some wishful thinking :)

Comment: @nawfal The lines are executing synchronously, you're just misunderstanding what `IOrderedEnumerable` gives you. It does not give you a thing which is already ordered, it gives you a thing which is promised to be ordered once you start enumerating. This is called deferred execution. You can read more about it via google.

Comment: @ean5533 Yes my comment was in a lighter vein. Nevertheless it's not as synchronously as one would expect (if not knowing about this deferred execution).

Comment: @nawfal This is one of the great things about LINQ, though it can be frustrating at times.  It makes a LOT of sense when you start looking at `IQueryable<T>`, though - without this "concept" in place, you'd have to hit the DB much more frequently.  Even with LINQ to Objects, it can be very beneficial - it's a big part of what allows PLINQ to "just work" the same way, for example.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Oh, I do not know anything about IQueryable. Thanks for timely updates. See my new edit which confirms what you said in answer. Thanks

Comment: @ReedCopsey In theory, Enumerable.Count could test if it's the specific concrete class used by Enumerable.OrderBy and if so call an internal method on it which calls count on the original sequence.

Comment: @Random832 Well - OrderBy would need to create some `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` implementation that implemented ICollection, so the count would be available.  But yes, this could have been done.  However, the current implementation does not do this.

Comment: .NET Core will indeed now skip ordering on `.OrderBy(…).Count()`. It's not a particularly worthwhile optimisation because really the calling code should just be fixed from `.OrderBy(…).Count()` anyway, but it was part and parcel with some other optimisations to both operations on the results of `OrderBy()` and to uses of `Count()` that fell into the same internal interface.

Answer (score 12):

`OrderBy()`, like most LINQ methods, uses deferred execution.

It doesn't actually do anything until you enumerate its results.

To properly measure its performance, you can call `.OrderBy(...).Count()`.

Comment: SLaks, could you explain the second sentence? I'm not very clear

Comment: BenchMark(persons => people = persons.OrderBy(n => n.Name)).Count();

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy()` does not create a sorted list.

It creates an IEnumerable object that, when you enumerate it, generates a sorted list.  The actual sorting doesn't happen until you enumerate the list.