# In LINQ to Objects, myCollection.Cast<MyType>().First() will cast the entire collection or just the first element?

Tags: .net, linq-to-objects

I want to know whether the `Cast()` operation is performed on the entire `IEnumerable<T>` or just on the filtered portion or it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at my question which is related and answers your question indirectly: [Order of LINQ extension methods does not affect performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq operations are deferred, only the first element will be cast and then returned.

You can try it yourself:

```
object[] objects = new object[] { 123, "string" };
objects.Cast<int>().First();
```

Comment: This is a good way of checking it out which I didn't think of. Thank you @strmstn