# How does OrderBy extension method orders collection

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have a class `Foo` which has an `Int32` Field `Bar` and you want to sort the collection of the `Foo` objects by the `Bar` Value. One way is to implement `IComparable`'s `CompareTo()` method, but it can also be done using Language Integrated Query (LINQ) like this

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
// assign some values here
var sortedFoos = foos.OrderBy(f => f.Bar);
```

now in `sortedFoos` we have `foos` collection which is sorted. But if you use `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` object to measure the time it took `OrderBy()` to sort the collection is always 0 milliseconds. But whenever you print `sortedFoos` collection it's obviously sorted. How is that possible. It takes literary no time to sort collection but after method execution the collection is sorted ? Can somebody explain to me how that works ? And also one thing. Suppose after sorting `foos` collection I added another element to it. now whenever I print out the collection the the element I added should be in the end right ? WRONG ! The `foos` collection will be sorted like, the element I added was the part of `foos` collection even if I add that element to `foos` after sorting. I don't quit understand how any of that work so can anybody make it clear for me ?!

Comment: Some of the LINQ methods are lazily evaluated - you can read up on [deferred execution here, examples with LINQ 2 XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx). The collection will be really ordered when it's materialized (by e.g. calling `ToList()`).

Comment: Because LINQ is deferred execution, you should call `ToList()` to trigger execution immediately

Comment: My own question a while ago is related and might help to understand linq's deferred execution because Eric/Jon has explained it very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ believe in deferred execution. This means the expression will only be evaluated when you started iterating or accessing the result.

Comment: _"With deferred execution, the above iterates your collection one time"_ This seems to be incorrect, `foos.OrderBy(f => f.Bar)` does not iterate the sequence (or original collection) at all. I assume it's just expressed inaccurately.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all LINQ methods use lazy evaluation - they don't immediately do anything, but they set up the query to do the right thing when you ask for the data.

`OrderBy` follows this model too - although it's less lazy than methods like `Where` and `Select`. When you ask for the *first* result from the result of `OrderBy`, it will read *all* the data from the source, sort *all* of it, and then return the first element. Compare this to `Select` for example, where asking for the first element from the projection only asks for the first element from the source.

If you're interested in how LINQ to Objects works behind the scenes, you might want to read my [Edulinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) - a complete reimplementation of LINQ to Objects, with a blog post describing each method's behaviour and implementation.

(In my own implementation of `OrderBy`, I actually only sort lazily - I use a quick sort and sort "just enough" to return the next element. This can make things like `largeCollection.OrderBy(...).First()` a lot quicker.)

Comment: My whole answer is inspired by reading your excellent linked blog. Kudos for rewriting the `IOrderedEnumerable` implementation but faster, without any "black magic."

Comment: @Jodrell: From what I remember around the time I was implementing it, it felt like very black magic indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `OrderBy` extension uses the deault `IComparer` for the type it is working on, unless an alternative is passed via the appropriate overload.

The sorting work is defered until the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` returned by your statement is first accessed. If you place the `Stopwatch` around that first access, you'll see how long sorting takes.

This makes a lot of sense, since your statement could be formed from multiple calls that return `IOrderedEnumerable`s. As the ordering calls are chained, they fluently extend the result, allowing the finally returned `IOrderedEnumerable` to perform the sorting in the most expedient way possible. This is probably achieved by chaining all the `IComparer` calls and sorting once. A greedy implementation would have to wastefully sort multiple times.

For instance, consider

```
class MadeUp
{
    public int A;
    public DateTime B;
    public string C;
    public Guid D;
}

var verySorted = madeUps.OrderBy(m => m.A)
                    .ThenBy(m => m.B)
                    .ThenByDescending(m => m.C)
                    .ThenBy(m => m.D);
```

If `verySorted` was evaluated greedily, then every property in the sequence would be evaluated and the sequence would be reordered 4 times. Because the linq implementation of `IOrderedEnumerable` deferes sorting until enumeration, it is able to optimise the process.

The `IComparer`s for `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` can be combined into a composite delegate, something like this simplified representation,

```
int result
result = comparerA(A, B);
if (result == 0)
{
    result = comparerB(A, B);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        result = comparerC(A, B);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            result = comparerD(A, B);
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

the composite delegate is then used to sort the sequence once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the ToList() to get a new collection. If you do't the OrderBy will be called when you start iterating on sortedFoos.

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
// assign some values here
var sortedFoos = foos.OrderBy(f => f.Bar).ToList();
```