# Difference between below two code snippets (Lambda Expressions)

Tags: c#, lambda

Can anyone please tell me the difference between the following two lambda expressions:

```
    1. TabView mytab = TabCollection.Where(s => s.TabHeader == h).FirstOrDefault();

    2. TabView mytab = TabCollection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TabHeader == h);
```

TabCollection is an ObservableCollection of type TabView.

Comment: I don't see any difference here.

Comment: [Order of LINQ extension methods does not affect performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance)

Comment: `Less code + same results` = `Better Code`. Use the second approach. type less. delay carpal tunnel.

Comment: When you separate both methods from each other you have more options. You can use the `Where` query lazily, so on each iteration or method call it could yield a different result. You could also chain other linq methods if desired(e.g. `OrderBy` or `Take(n)`) whereas the `FirstOrDefault` "ends" the query. However, the second approach is a little bit more effficient and - more important - more readable since it's more direct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two statements will provide the same results.

The difference is in how the result is achieved.  The second is *slightly* more efficient, as it does not need to generate an iterator for the `Where` method, and then get it's enumerator, and can instead directly enumerate the collection until a match is found.

Comment: the difference is incredibly slight

Comment: @LukeMcGregor There is an extra iterator allocated for handling the Where enumeration - it's minor, but in a tight loop or performant code, avoiding allocations can be important.  It'd be tough to measure in anything except a tight loop, though, since any gain would likely be reduced GC pressure more than saved CPU cycles.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Good point about GC pressure :) Space complexity is often overlooked.

Comment: Essentially, the two options are nearly identical - but they aren't technically identical, and the second is potentially better (hence the overload exists)

Comment: @Luke - The entirety of the `Where` condition must be met before continuing on to the next method. This means that if there are millions of items in the collection the `Where` method would need to visit millions of items to see if the condition were met. Then the next method `FirstOrDefault` would take the first match of the iterator. Whereas the `FirstOrDefault` method will break out at the first match, potentially saving millions of conditional checks.

Comment: @TravisJ That is completely untrue.  The Where() method returns an *iterator*, not a fully populated collection.  When `FirstOrDefault` starts enumerating the `IEnumerable<T>` returned from `Where`, it enumerates it in a deferred, streaming manner.  Both versions will still short circuit and stop checking once a match is found.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - So the first yield returned value from where will make it to firstordefault and cause the execution to stop at that point? My point was that building the enumerable in the `Where` method requires checking every item. Is that not the case? Does the `FirstOrDefault` method check for values when `Where` starts building the enumerable?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes - the first yield returned which exists (from first or default) will "stop" the Where iterator from continuing.  `Where` does not need to check every item - it will only check items as FirstOrDefault enumerates them, which means it'll only check until a match is found and then stop.

Answer (score 3):

```
TabCollection.Where(s => s.TabHeader == h).FirstOrDefault()
```

This creates `WhereIterator` and returns it. Then you starting iteration and return first element of it. That looks like

```
var iterator = new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(TabCollection, predicate);

using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = iterator.GetEnumerator())
{
   if (enumerator.MoveNext())
       return enumerator.Current;
}

return default(TSource);
```

Second one does not create iterator - it simply enumerates over source:

```
TabCollection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TabHeader == h);
```

Same as

```
foreach (TSource local in TabCollection)
{
    if (predicate(local))        
        return local;        
}

return default(TSource);
```

So, second option is slightly more efficient.