# Subgroup of list

Tags: c#, list

I have a 2 list of string.
Is there a simple way to find if one list contains all the strings of the 2nd list?

(By saying simple, I mean that I don't have explicitly compare for each string in one list to all the strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
firstList.All(x=>secondList.Contains(x));
```

Shorter version (method group):

```
firstList.All(secondList.Contains)
```

You need to write using for Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

It ckeckes wheter All items from first list are in second list. `Contains` checks if given item is in list. `All` gives true if all items of collections are matching predicate. Given predicate is: if item is in second list, so whole expresion checks if all items are in second list <- proved working :)

Comment: LOL, linq questions go so fast these days

Comment: @DavidColwell especially those simple :)

Comment: Here also, more readable (and maybe more efficient) with a delegate instead of a lambda: `firstList.All(secondList.Contains)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Gotta love going to a simple LINQ question and learning something. I didn't know that you could pass the method groups in, but it makes so much sense!

Answer (score 5):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to find differences between lists. If there is no items in result, then all items from list2 are in list1:

```
bool containsAll = !list2.Except(list1).Any();
```

Internally `Except` uses `Set<T>` to get unique items from `list1` and returns only that items from `list2` which are not in set. If there is nothing to return, then all items in set.

Answer (score 3):

For larger lists use a `HashSet<T>` (which results in linear Big O, as opposed to O(n^2) when just using two lists):

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>(list2);
bool containsAll = list1.All(hash.Contains);
```

Comment: Even shorter `list1.All(hash.Contains)` :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah true, I always let Resharper remind me of method group conversions - much more readable too

Comment: For short lists, i think LINQ O(n^2) would be faster because of the setup time on the hashset, but i havent run the stats... would be interested to see how many results are required before it becomes viable

Comment: @DavidColwell For some perspective, creating the HashSet is about as expensive as two `Contains` calls on a `List`, so a `List` will likely only be faster if there are one or two items in the list; maybe up to as many as three or four.  For collections *that* small, performance is irrelevant.  As soon as the collection size is large enough to matter in any way, the `List` solution will be *much* slower.  So the end result is that there's really no reason to ever use a `List` to do this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Was just commenting because the question commented that the search is O instead of O(N^2), realistically this will rarely be the source of performance problems

Comment: @Servy, See my answer. Your comment is incorrect when testing with a set of size 5,000,000

Answer (score 0):

use LINQ

```
bool isSublistOf = list1.All(list2.Contains);
```

The All method returns true if the condition in the lambda is met for every element in the `IEnumerable`. The All is passed the Contains method of List2 as the `Func<bool,string>` which returns true if the element is found `List2`.  The net effect is that the statement returns true if ALL of the elements in List1 are found in List2.

**Performance Note**
Due to the nature of the All operator, it is worst case O(n^2), but will exit at the first chance (any mismatch). Using completely random 8 byte strings, I tried out each of the cases using a rudimentary performance harness.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long count = 5000000;
        //Get 5,000,000 random strings (the superset)
        var strings = CreateRandomStrings(count);

        //Get 1000 random strings (the subset)
        var substrings = CreateRandomStrings(1000);

        //Perform the hashing technique
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        var hash = new HashSet<string>(strings);
        var mid = DateTime.Now;
        var any = substrings.All(hash.Contains);
        var end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Hashing took " + end.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds + " " + mid.Subtract(start).Milliseconds + " of which was setting up the hash");

        //Do the scanning all technique
        start = DateTime.Now;
        any = substrings.All(strings.Contains);
        end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning took " + end.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);

        //Do the Excepting technique
        start = DateTime.Now;
        any = substrings.Except(strings).Any();
        end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Excepting took " + end.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static string[] CreateRandomStrings(long count)
    {
        var rng = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        string[] strings = new string[count];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

        for (long i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            rng.NextBytes(bytes);
            strings[i] = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
        return strings;
    }
```

The result ranked them in the following order fairly consistently:

1. Scanning - ~38ms (`list1.All(list2.Contains)`)
2. Hashing - ~750ms (749 of which was spent setting up the hashset)
3. Excepting - 1200ms

The excepting method takes much longer because it requires all the work up front. Unlike the other methods, it will not exit on a mismatch, but continue to process all elements. The Hashing is much faster, but also does significant work up front in setting up the hash. This would be the fastest method **if** the strings were less random and intersections were more certain.

**Disclaimer**
All performance tuning at this level is next to irrelevant. This is just a mental exercise only

Comment: So, lots of problems here.  1) you're running teach test *only once*.  2) There is no run to warm up the JIT 3) `DateTime` is *horrible* at measuring performance; it just doesn't have enough precision

Comment: Sticking it in a loop results in comparable results. Feel free to post some negative results if you have any

Comment: Try running it when `substrings` actually *is* a subset of `strings`.  This can be done by, as it's creation process, taking 1000 random strings from `strings`.  See how that affects your results.  You can also test some "close but not quite" sets in which say 70-95% of the strings are taken from the `strings` collection and the remainder are not.  Due to the nature of `All`, which is what we're doing, the first non-match means you're done.  Your solution involves *most* not matching.  The probability of the first item not matching is actually *very* high.

Comment: Tracking the Intersect of the two, as the subset approaches a complete subset, the hashset rapidly becomes faster.

Comment: @DavidColwell Exactly.  You were measuring the best case of one algorithm against the worst case of the other, among the other problems.

Comment: "Except" does not need to process all the items due to LINQ's deferred execution. "Any" will also stop immediately. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance