# Lazily filtering list

Tags: c#

I have a list of items, and I want to select 3 items from that list that fulfills a predicate.

I've tried this: (examples)

`list.Where(x => x == 2).Take(3)`

`list.Take(3).Where(x => x == 2)`

But of course they don't work.

Is there a mechanism that only selects elements that meets a predicate until the `.Take(3)` is fulfilled?

EDIT: The problem with the first example is that it first selects EVERY element that matches, then takes the first 3. I only want it to select until it has taken 3. I suppose it only really matters on huge collections, but still. Or that's how I understand it anyway.

This happens: (**edit: I was wrong about this**)

`[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2].Where(x => x == 2)` => `[2, 2, 2, 2].Take(3)` => `[2, 2, 2]`

I want something like:
`[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2].Where(x => x == 2, 3)` => `[2, 2, 2]`, where the 3 is the number of elements it matches before it stops filtering.

Comment: The first example looks fine, provided you want 3 items that match the predicate.  The second won't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Your first example should work, so you need to be more specific about how it doesn't. Make sure you are actually trying to enumerate the sequence returned from `Take`.

Comment: Why does your first example not work?

Comment: What makes you think your first version does not do what you want?

Comment: Could you post an example to show what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have updated with an edit.

Comment: Given your edit, why is that a problem? Do you have a huge dataset?

Comment: Still unclear after edit. Can you post a data sample and a subset of it you want to get as a result?

Comment: Your edit is incorrect, `Where` and `Take` are both lazy, so it will only search for three matches. Once the third is found it will not keep finding matches and discarding them.

Comment: Is it Linq to SQL or Linq to Objects?

Comment: Ah, ok, seems I was wrong. Linq has deferred execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you've not understood linq's deferred execution. Your first approach does exactly what you want:

```
list.Where(x => x == 2).Take(3)
```

It checks every item but just until it has found three items matching the predicate.

Have a look at Eric Lipperts answer on my question since he explains it very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110269/284240

This is also worth reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will select this as the correct answer when I can.