# Will a LINQ expression returning multiple items followed by the First method iterate through all items in the preceding method in .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

In the following statement will the where method iterate through all elements before First is executed on the returned elements, or will the First method take effect already in the Where method? In VB.NET:

```
Items.Where(Function(Item) Item.IsMatch).First
```

Items implements IEnumerable(Of T)

Comment: Read my own question asked some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance

Comment: It depends on the filter. In a worst case it will loop through the whole set and raise an exception on First.

Comment: @TimSchmelter read it, and I'm glad to hear that it works as I was hoping!

Comment: @WiktorZychla If used on a collection where not finding an element is a possibility, I will use FirstOrDefault instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Where`:

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated.

That is when `First()` is invoked on `Where`s output, which in turn invokes `GetEnumerator`.